# Adding class/object to Array list if not a duplicate value present

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Im having a hard time understanding what is happing with my logic. My goal is to add objects to an arraylist if a string on the object is not already present on current arraylist im making.

So to explain my code below/my intentions..

while I add to `rowItems` check for versionId that already has been added to `rowItems` and if so append the name of the current object.

Here is what I have so far:

```
      rowItems = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < SearchResultsHolder.results.size(); i++) {
                SearchRowItem item = new SearchRowItem(SearchResultsHolder.results.get(i).get("LAST_NAME").toString() + ", " + SearchResultsHolder.results.get(i).get("FIRST_NAME").toString(),
                        SearchResultsHolder.results.get(i).get("BUSINESS_NAME").toString(),
                        SearchResultsHolder.results.get(i).get("LOB").toString(),
                        SearchResultsHolder.results.get(i).get("ID_NUMBER").toString(),
                        cleanCancelled(SearchResultsHolder.results.get(i).get("STATUS").toString()),
                        SearchResultsHolder.results.get(i).get("EFF_DATE").toString(),
                        SearchResultsHolder.results.get(i).get("EXP_DATE").toString(),
                        SearchResultsHolder.results.get(i).get("VERSION_ID").toString());

                if (i == 0){
                    rowItems.add(item);//add first object by default

                }

                else {
                    for (int p = 0; p < rowItems.size(); p++) {
                        // if the version id is equal to any of the others already in the rowItems array appent the name to the object already in the array
                        if (item.getVersionId().toString().equals(rowItems.get(p).getVersionId().toString()))
                        {
                            item.setName(item.getName().toString() + "\n" + rowItems.get(p).getName().toString());
                          break;
                        } else {
                            rowItems.add(item);

                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            System.out.println("row item" + rowItems.toString());
```

SearchResults holder has a layout like this:

```
[
    {
        VERSION_ID=50,
        STATUS=Active,
        ID_NUMBER=1234,
        FIRST_NAME=JOHN,
        LAST_NAME=DOE       
    },
        {
        VERSION_ID=50,
        STATUS=Active,
        ID_NUMBER=1234,
        FIRST_NAME=JANE,
        LAST_NAME=DOE       
    },
        {
        VERSION_ID=100,
        STATUS=Dead,
        ID_NUMBER=1234,
        FIRST_NAME=JOHN,
        LAST_NAME=DOE       
    },
    {
        VERSION_ID=100,
        STATUS=Dead,
        ID_NUMBER=1234,
        FIRST_NAME=JANE,
        LAST_NAME=DOE       
    },
]
```

And what Im trying to achieve with the objects in my class: (rowitems arraylist)

```
[
    {
        VERSION_ID=50,
        STATUS=Active,
        ID_NUMBER=1234,
        NAME=JANE,DOE
             JOHN,DOE      
    },
        {
        VERSION_ID=100,
        STATUS=Dead,
        ID_NUMBER=1234,
        NAME=JANE,DOE
             JOHN,DOE
    },

]
```

What I get :

```
[
    {
        VERSION_ID=50,
        STATUS=Dead,
        ID_NUMBER=1234,
        NAME=JOHN,DOE



    },
        {
        VERSION_ID=100,
        STATUS=Active,
        ID_NUMBER=1234,
        NAME=JOHN,DOE

    }


]
```

Comment: And what actually happens when you run it?

Comment: @DavidConrad Added what I get from it

Comment: Did you try stepping through with a debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have incorrect this condition.

```
if (item.getVersionId().toString().equals(rowItems.get(p).getVersionId().toString()))
                {
                    item.setName(item.getName().toString() + "\n" + rowItems.get(p).getName().toString());
                } else {
                    rowItems.add(item);

                }
```

It means now when not equals strings you add it to arraylist. It is not correct. You have to **check if all values from rowItems are not equals** to item string. Idea like this:

```
 boolean foundDup = false;
 for (int p = 0; p < rowItems.size(); p++) {

                // if the version id is equal to any of the others already in the rowItems array appent the name to the object already in the array
                if (item.getVersionId().toString().equals(rowItems.get(p).getVersionId().toString()))
                {
                    rowItems.get(p).setName(item.getName().toString() + "\n<ToSeeEndOfLine>" + rowItems.get(p).getName().toString()); // EDIT: this line is changed
                    foundDup = true;
                    break;
                } 
            }
     if (!foundDup)
            rowItems.add(item);
```

Comment: To make it more efficient, you should also add a break after it has been found.

Comment: @kolisko I added the break and it did help get closer to what Im looking for but still not there, see new output with break added in for loop

Comment: What is the current output and current code you are using now?

Comment: Ah, I see you edited it. You your new code with "break" is still incorrect. Check my example, there is added the "foundDup" variable and the "if" condition outside the for-loop.

Comment: @kolisko Ok thats works a lot better! Still not getting the name appended on, will have to do some testing to see why. See my updated output

Comment: @BluGeni I changed one line of code, check the line "rowItems.get(p).setName(item.getName().toString() + "\n<ToSeeEndOfLine>" + rowItems.get(p).getName().toString());". What is the exact output of my new code now?

Comment: OH Man it works! Thank you so much for helping me and explaining what I was doing wrong!